# twig variable not found in javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I'm trying to pass a twig array variable to javascript, but for some reason it keeps stating that the variable does not exist.

My twig:

```
{% set clients = [] %}
{% for work in works %}

    {% set clients = clients|merge([ work.name ]) %}

{% endfor %}

{% set client_array = clients|json_encode|raw  %}
```

When I try and call client array with `{{client_array}}` I have no trouble whatsoever, it returns the correct array.

However my problem is when I try to define a javascript variable below in a javascript block on the page to be equal to client_array.

```
<script>
var clients = '{{ client_array }}';
...
 </script>
```

I keep getting

> Variable "client_array" does not exist.

I feel there's some dumb syntax error I'm making here.  Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: do you have actual `{% block %}` blocks in that template (or is it a different template)? if so, then it's possibly a scope issue. also: the quotes are probably a problem, if the var is json encoded, but not related to the twig error.

Comment: They were in actual blocks in the template.  Scope was what I was able to figure out by elimination.  It seems to have something to do with "set" variables within a twig not appearing in different blocks.  I chose to create the array in the controller instead, and that variable was able to be passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so I took a different approach to this and chose to set the variable in the controller and that worked

```
    $clients = [];
    foreach ($works as $work) {
        $client = $work['name'];
        array_push($clients, $client);
    }
```

While comparing the output side by side, they were identical, so my conclusion is that it appears that twig "set" variables don't seem to be recognized outside the block.  (don't quote me on this)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Passing Information from Twig to JavaScript](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/frontend/encore/server-data.html)

In controller create variable:

```
public function index(Request $request) {

    /* ... */
    $clients = array(array("id" => 1, "name" => "test1"), array("id" => 2, "name" => "test2"));
    $names = array_map(function ($ar) {
        return $ar['name'];
    }, $clients);
    $twigparms = array("clients" => $names);
    return $this->render("YourTemplate/index.html.twig", $twigparms);
}
```

in Twig use it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title>Page Title</title>
    <body>

        <div class="clients" id="clients" data-names="{{ clients|json_encode|e('html_attr') }}"></div>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                var clientstmp = document.querySelector('.clients');
                var clients = clientstmp.dataset.names;
                console.log(clients);
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```